# Linux Mint cannot access USB drive from an admin accout. Drive is detected and works fine in other accounts on the same machine

Tags: files, linux-mint, usb-drive

I have a weird problem on a Linux Mint 18.3 Serena Mate install. USB drives (I have tried a few) are detected and appear on the desktop but cannot be accessed in this account. The account has admin privileges but I can only access the USB drive if I go into terminal and become root (sudo su). Using the "Files" application, I get the message "Could not display "/media/accountname/drivename". The location is not a folder."  In the terminal I get a simple "access denied" until I elevate to root when it works fine. In other accounts it just works Does anyone know what setting I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Are you logging in locally or remotely over SSH? Is your user account currently a member of the `plugdev` group? (run `id` to check)

Comment: I am logging in locally. I actually deleted the account and transferred the files to a new account that was working. The computer is also connected to an Active Directory domain and the AD accounts won't even mount USBs now!